# Как организовать владение одним экземпляром класса коллекции из объектов наследников абстрактного класса qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt, ооп

Имеется абстрактный класс `IAction`:

```
enum ActionResult_t
{
    RESULT_UNKNOWN,
    RESULT_IN_PROCESS,
    RESULT_ERROR,
    RESULT_FINISH
};

struct IAction
{
    friend class ActionsEnivroment;
protected:

    ActionsEnivroment& enivroment;

public:

    QThreadStorage<QCache<char, double>> args;

    explicit IAction(ActionsEnivroment& ae) : enivroment(ae)
    {}

    virtual bool isCorrected(QString&) = 0;

    virtual void serializate(std::ostream&) = 0;
    virtual void deserializate(std::istream&) = 0;

    virtual void startExecution(){}
    virtual ActionResult_t execute(ManipulatorController&, qint64) = 0;
    virtual void endExecution(){}

    virtual ~IAction(){}
};
```

Также имеется класс `ActionsEnivroment`

```
class ActionsEnivroment
{

public:

    //Some variables and methods

    ActionsEnivroment() = default;

    template<typename T>
    T* createAction()
    {
        T* act = new T(*this);
        //???
        return act;
    }

    bool deleteAction(IAction* a)
    {
        //???
        return true;
    }

};
```

Как реализовать механизм, в котором `ActionsEnivroment` является владельцем для всех наследников класса `IIAction`. При этом только он может создать и удалить их?

---

Я пытался реализовать `std::list<std::shared_ptr<IAction>>` внутри `ActionsEnivroment`, где хранились бы объекты всех созданных классов, но возникли ошибки.

Comment: непонятно, нужно c++ наследование или Qt  через QObject::setParent()?

Comment: @PavelGridin setparent здесь не причем. Думал использовать внутри ActionsEnivroment коллекцию shared_ptr<Iaction> или что-то такое.

Comment: ¿Если не собираетесь использовать организацию владения объектами qt, то зачем вообще его упоминать в вопросе?

Comment: @user7860670 Потому что сама программа создается на qt. Я подразумевал, что реально использовать структуры данных и готовые механизмы qt.

Comment: *готовые механизмы qt* - ну тогда используйте упомянутый `QObject::setParent()`